# Mad Libs using recursive IO for user input

Tags: beginner, haskell, formatting

I'm writing my first small programs in Haskell and still getting a feel for the syntax and idioms. I've written this Mad Libs implementation using recursive IO. I've used IO actions throughout and I'm sure there must be a better way of splitting up this code to separate pure functions from IO actions. Also, I'm not happy with the printf statement, but I couldn't find a native way to apply an arbitrary number of list items to printf.

```
import Text.Printf

getAnswer :: String -> IO String
getAnswer question = do
    putStrLn question
    answer <- getLine
    return answer

getAnswers :: [String] -> [String] -> IO [String]
getAnswers [] ys = return ys
getAnswers (x:xs) ys = do
    answer <- getAnswer x
    let answers = ys ++ [answer]
    getAnswers xs answers

main = do
    let questions = ["Enter a noun:", "Enter a verb:", "Enter an adjective:", "Enter an adverb:"]
    let madlib = "Your %s is %s up a %s mountain %s."
    answers <- getAnswers questions []
    printf madlib (answers!!0) (answers!!1) (answers!!2) (answers!!3)
    putStrLn ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can we make `getAnswer` simpler or out of `IO`? Well, not really. You want to ask the use a question, and you want to get an answer. So all we could do is to reduce the amount of unnecessary code:

```
getAnswer :: String -> IO String
getAnswer question = putStrLn question >> getLine
-- or
--                 = do
--      putStrLn question
--      getLine
```

However, `getAnswers` can be refactored quite heavily. First of all, its interface isn't really developer-friendly. What are the questions? What are the answers? We should probably hide that in the bowels of our function:

```
getAnswers :: [String] -> IO [String]
getAnswers xs = go xs [] 
  where go [] ys = return ys
        go (x:xs) ys = do
          answer <- getAnswer x
          let answers = ys ++ [answer]
          go xs answers
```

But `++ [...]` isn't really best-practice. Instead, you would ask all other questions and then combine them:

```
  where go [] = return []
        go (x:xs) = do
          answer <- getAnswer x
          otherAnswers <- getAnswers x
          return (answer : otherAnswers)
```

But at that point, we're merily copying `mapM`'s functionailty. Therefore, your `getAnswers` should be

```
getAnswers :: [String] -> IO [String]
getAnswers = mapM getAnswer
```

A lot simpler.

Now for your `main`. If you don't know how many words you'll get you will need a list, correct. But lets check the structure of your result:

```
 "Your %s is %s up a %s mountain %s."
       1     2       3           4
```

There is a pattern. We have our text, then whatever the user gave us, then again our text, and so on. Let's split that into fragments:

```
["Your ","%s"," is ","%s"," up a ","%s"," mountain ","%s","."]
--       ^^^^        ^^^^          ^^^^              ^^^^
```

This brings up the following idea: if you have a list of your answers, you only need the list of the other words, right?

```
["Your "," is "," up a "," mountain ","."]
```

And then we need to "zip" that list with yours:

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
interleave xs     _      = xs
```

We end up with the following `main`:

```
main = do
    let questions = ["Enter a noun:", "Enter a verb:", "Enter an adjective:", "Enter an adverb:"]
    let madlib = ["Your "," is "," up a "," mountain ","."]
    answers <- getAnswers questions

    putStrLn $ interleave madlib questions
```

Here's all the code at once:

```
getAnswer :: String -> IO String
getAnswer q = putStrLn q >> getLine

getAnswers :: [String] -> IO [String]
getAnswers = mapM getAnswer

interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
interleave xs     _      = xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let questions = ["Enter a noun:", "Enter a verb:", "Enter an adjective:", "Enter an adverb:"]
    let madlib = ["Your "," is "," up a "," mountain ","."]
    answers <- getAnswers questions

    putStrLn $ interleave madlib questions
```

## Exercises

The `interleave` function above is left-biased. Why? Could this pose problems for your program? Why not?

Comment: Thanks for such an in depth review, it's given me a lot of good feedback.